# How does partial word lookup work in an inverted index?

Tags: data-structures, database-theory

I know that an inverted index is a mapping from `words -> documents`. In the database I'm using, I'm able to do a search for `apple*`, and it will return `apple banana`, `banana apple banana`, and `applepie`. The one that confuses me is `applepie`. I assumed the inverted index would only have the word `applepie` in the mapping from `words -> documents`. How could this result of returning `applepie` be achieved? Does the inverted index also store the values `a`, `ap`,... `apple`,... and which documents they map to, or something else?

(The database is unimportant but it's MySQL full text search.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping from word to postings almost certainly uses some variant of a B-tree, storing case-folded (and possibly stemmed) string keys in lexicographic order. With that data structure, prefix search can be implemented as a straightforward index scan.

Other kinds of partial search (e.g. substring search, or hamming-distance search) would be much slower, or require a different data structure.